# Function inside of onClick tag out of scope in dojo 1.6

Tags: javascript, foreach, onclick, dojo, dom-events

I am making buttons in a `forEach` loop but when I try to have a function for the `onClick` tag of a button it says `this.foo()` is not a function. The code is as follows:

```
    dojo.forEach(buttonIds, function(btn, i) {
               var button = new dijit.form.Button({
                    id: buttonIds[i]+'.'+widgetId,
                    label: buttonLabel[i],
                    onClick: function () {
                        dojo.hitch(this, this.foo());}
});
```

Now maybe `dojo.connect()` is more appropriate here but I don't know how would I get the button ID as the first argument because if I understand correctly then connect would look something like `dojo.connect(button.id, 'onClick', this, foo())`. Unfortunately this statement also results in the same error. This may be a trivial scoping problem but I am very new at dojo so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry for `dojo.connect()` the error is `button is undefined`

Comment: So if I do something like `onClick: this.foo` that seems to be working for one button but it doesn't implement `onClick` for all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I think the connect should look like:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId(buttonIds[i]+'.'+widgetId), 'onclick', this.foo);
```

notice lower case **'c'** in **'onclick'** and no **'()'** after foo.

As for the `onClick` argument in the button constructor, `dojo.hitch` takes in and returns a function which is executed in the scope of the first argument so:

```
onClick:dojo.hitch(this, this.foo);
```

should work

you were trying to hitch in the execution of the function instead of the function itself (notice no '();' after function name)

Answer (score 1):

`dojo.forEach` accepts actually three parameters ([source](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/arrays/)):

> The dojo.forEach method accepts three (3) arguments: an array to
>   iterate over, a function (or callback) to call for each item of the
>   array (including unassigned indexes between assigned ones, as
>   described above), and **an optional object to use as the scope in which
>   to call the callback**.

Your `this` in `dojo.hitch` points to the callback function, add `this` as third parameter:

```
dojo.forEach(buttonIds, function(item, index, items) { /*callback*/ }, this);

// or alternatively
var self = this;
dojo.forEach(buttonIds, function(item, index, items) { /*use self instead of this here*/ });
```

I am not sure what are you about to achieve, but here is my guess:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

dojo.ready(function() {

    dojo.declare("Spam", null, {

        constructor: function() {
            this.buttonIds = ["button1", "button2", "button3"];         
        },

        createButtons: function() {
            dojo.forEach(this.buttonIds, function(item, index, items) {
                var button = new dijit.form.Button({
                    id: item,
                    label: item
                });
                button.onClick = dojo.hitch(this, "foo", button);
                button.placeAt(dojo.body());
            }, this);      
        },

        foo: function(widget, event) {
            console.log(widget.id);
        }
    });

    var spam = new Spam();
    spam.createButtons();

});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/mcnjt/